# mongo-express connection problem with docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, mongo-express

I'm trying to set up docker running mongodb with docker-express and deployd.

Mongodb seems to be working just fine but mongo-express keeps throwing me the same error. I tried almost everything with the parameter as I am quite sure that there's something wrong with the mongo-express configuration.

Here's my docker-compose.yml configuration for mongo and mongo-express:

[image]

The purple boxes contain the same credentials.

Here's a screenshot of the docker logs for the mongo-express container.

[image]

When I checked other similar issues, most of those where solved by modifying the MONGODB_URL, but in this case the URL seems just fine to me. Let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: try using the service name (`mongo`) instead of the container name for the mongodb_server environment variable (`pst-mongo`). also not that it matters but you left your username in the error image

Comment: I just tried, exact same error @NoamYizraeli

Comment: Just to make sure, your new error specifies the following connection string? `mongodb://user:pass@mongo:27017`

Comment: yes that's it, having the credentials in the purple box as user and pass respectively.

Comment: Also, your mongo service uses a custom network `pst-net` while the express one uses the default one

Comment: @NoamYizraeli yes that's because of the connection between mongodb and deployd. Shall I use the same network with mongo-express?

Comment: If you want them to be able to connect then yes

Comment: That solved the issue, I can now connect. Thank you so much. Can you please answer the question so I can valid your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The containers didn't use the same docker network and the DNS record used for connecting to the mongo server was using the container name instead of the service name.

After checking these misconfigurations the issue was resolved